# How to parse records line by line and print only selected fields

Tags: python, parsing

I have a huge file with the structure similar to:

```
PMID- 1
OWN - NLM
STAT- PubMed-not-MEDLINE
LR  - 20191218
TI  - Synthesis and Characterization of a Fluorescence Probe of the Phase Transition
      and Dynamic Properties of Membranes.
PG  - 5714-5722
LID - 10.1021/bi00294a006 [doi]
AB  - We describe the synthesis and characterization of a new fluorescence probe whose 
      emission spectra, anisotropies, and wavelength-dependent decay times are highly
      sensitive to the phase state of phospholipid vesicles. 
PST - ppublish
SO  - Biochemistry.

PMID- 2
STAT- Publisher
PB  - National Academies Press (US)
TI  - The National Academies Collection: Reports funded by National Institutes of
      Health
AID - NBK547296 [bookaccession]
AID - 10.17226/19375 [doi]

PMID- 3
STAT- Publisher
DA  - 20140815
ISBN- 030903339X
PB  - National Academies Press (US)
DP  - 1983
BTI - Community Oriented Primary Care: New Directions for Health Services Delivery
CN  - Institute of Medicine (US) Division of Health Care Services
```

The **task** is to print lines with `PMID`, `TI`, and `AB` fields only, with the following constraints:

- Print PMID field only if TI field is present in a record
- Records should be separated with a single blank line

In original data `AB` field is present only if `TI` field is present in the record. The result should be:

```
PMID- 1
TI  - Synthesis and Characterization of a Fluorescence Probe of the Phase Transition
      and Dynamic Properties of Membranes.
AB  - We describe the synthesis and characterization of a new fluorescence probe whose 
      emission spectra, anisotropies, and wavelength-dependent decay times are highly
      sensitive to the phase state of phospholipid vesicles.

PMID- 2
TI  - The National Academies Collection: Reports funded by National Institutes of
      Health
```

The current solution is:

```
import re

with open("input.txt", "rt") as in_file:
    prog = re.compile("^(....)- (.*)$")
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        match = prog.match(line)
        if match:
            tag = match.groups()[0]
            field = match.groups()[1]
        # If "PMID" tag, print it but only if "TI" field is present in the record
        if tag == "PMID":
            pmid = line
        # If "TI" line, print it
        if tag == "TI  ":
            print(line)
            ti_line = True
        # If line is a "continuation line" and we are in TI field
        elif line.startswith("      ") and ti_line:
            print(line)
        else:
            ti_line = False
        # If "AB" line, print it
        if tag == "AB  ":
            print(line)
            ab_line = True      
        # If line is a "continuation line" and we are in AB field
        elif line.startswith("      ") and ab_line:
            print(line)
        else:
            ab_line = False
```

with the output:

```
TI  - Synthesis and Characterization of a Fluorescence Probe of the Phase Transition
      and Dynamic Properties of Membranes.
AB  - We describe the synthesis and characterization of a new fluorescence probe whose
      emission spectra, anisotropies, and wavelength-dependent decay times are highly
      sensitive to the phase state of phospholipid vesicles.
TI  - The National Academies Collection: Reports funded by National Institutes of
      Health
```

**Questions:**

- What is the best way to include `PMID`s in the output?
- How to separe records with the blank line?

Comment: I would print only when I get empty line (`if not line:`) because it is end of record and I can check if I get `TI` so I can print `PMID`

Comment: It's a crazy file format, you should definitely consider converting it to some machine-friendly format (e.g. CSV), and then processing would be much easier

Comment: Do you need the output to be in the same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Print lines with `PMID`, `TI`, and `AB` fields only, with constraints

Aggregate all lines, in a `dict`, until a blank line occurs, indicating the end of a record.
Check the aggregated record against your constraints and process accordingly.

> **ASSUMPTION**: The longest id length is `4` (`'PMID'`) and all id right padded with blanks.
>   Lines, starts with `6` blanks, belongs to the previous line.

```
DATA = """PMID- 1
OWN - NLM
STAT- PubMed-not-MEDLINE ... (omitted for brevity)"""

import io

def process_record(record):
    if 'TI' in record:
        print('Record {} is {} lines and has {}'.format(record['PMID'], len(record), record.keys()))
        for key in ['PMID', 'TI', 'AB']:
            field = record.get(key, None) 
            if field is not None:
                print(field)
        print()

#with open("input.txt", "rt") as in_file:
with io.StringIO(DATA) as in_file:
    record = {}

    for line in in_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if len(line):
            if line.startswith(' '*6):
                # concat with previous line
                record[key] = ''.join((record[key], line[5:]))
            else:
                key = line[:4].rstrip()
                record[key] = line
        else:
            process_record(record)            
            record = {}

# Process the last record if any
if record:
    process_record(record)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Record PMID- 1 is 10 lines and has dict_keys(['PMID', 'OWN', 'STAT', 'LR', 'TI', 'PG', 'LID', 'AB', 'PST', 'SO'])
> PMID- 1
> TI  - Synthesis and Characterization of a Fluorescence Probe ... (omitted for brevity)
> AB  - We describe the synthesis and characterization of a new ... (omitted for brevity)
>
> Record PMID- 2 is 5 lines and has dict_keys(['PMID', 'STAT', 'PB', 'TI', 'AID'])
> PMID- 2
> TI  - The National Academies Collection: Reports funded by Nat... (omitted for brevity)
>
> Record PMID- 3 is 8 lines and has dict_keys(['PMID', 'STAT', 'DA', 'ISBN', 'PB', 'DP', 'BTI', 'CN'])
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the output to be in the same format as input I would do something like this:

```
import json


def convert_to_json(input, output) -> None:
    current_object = {}
    current_tag = None

    for line in input:
        if not line.strip():
            # empty line
            # we need to save object into output file
            output.write(json.dumps(current_object) + "\n")
            current_object = {}
            current_tag = None
            continue

        if line.startswith("      "):
            # it is continuation of previous tag
            assert current_tag
            current_object[current_tag] = current_object[current_tag] + " " + line.strip()
        else:
            # we found a new tag
            tag, value = line.strip().split('-', 1)
            tag = tag.strip()
            value = value.strip()

            current_tag = tag
            current_object[tag] = value

    # save the last object manually
    # because file may not contain empty line at the end
    if current_object:
        output.write(json.dumps(current_object) + "\n")


# STAGE 1: transform input file into more machine-friendly format
# for example, JSON rows
with open("input.txt", "rt") as input:
    with open('output.json', 'w') as output:
        convert_to_json(input, output)


# STAGE 2: print any information you need
# format it as you need
with open('output.json') as new_input:
    for line in new_input:
        obj = json.loads(line.strip())
        if "PMID" in obj and "TI" in obj:
            print(obj["PMID"])
        if "TI" in obj:
            print(obj["TI"])
        if "AB" in obj:
            print(obj["AB"])
        print()
```

As I understand it would be non-trivial (but possible of course) to save source data format, because tags in input stream may be in any order (for example, PMID may come before TI but they also may come in reverse order).